# How to correctly do HttpResponseRedirect with reverse?

Tags: python, django

I am getting an error "_reverse_with_prefix() argument after * must be a sequence, not int" when I try to reverse.  I previously hardcoded the parameter in the view but am trying to make it dynamic.  Any advice?

View:

```
def add_review(request, product_id):
    p = get_object_or_404(Product, pk=product_id)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = ReviewForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            #HARDCODED: return HttpResponseRedirect('/products/1/reviews/')
            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('view_reviews', args=(p.id)))
    else:
        form = ReviewForm()
    variables = RequestContext(request, {'form': form})
    return render_to_response('reserve/templates/create_review.html', variables)        


def view_reviews(request, product_id):
    product = get_object_or_404(Product, pk=product_id)
    reviews = Review.objects.filter(product_id=product_id)
    return render_to_response('reserve/templates/view_reviews.html', {'product':product, 'reviews':reviews},
    context_instance=RequestContext(request))


urlpatterns = patterns('reserve.views',
    url(r'^clubs/$', 'index'),
    url(r'^products/(?P<product_id>\d+)/reviews/$', 'view_reviews'),
    url(r'^products/(?P<product_id>\d+)/add_review/$', 'add_review'),
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
)
```

Comment: Also see the redirect shortcut https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/shortcuts/#redirect

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Check `args=(p.id)` inside the `reverse()`, it must be `args=(p.id,)`. The first form is treated as integer instead of a sequence.

Refs [the doc](http://docs.python.org/reference/datamodel.html#the-standard-type-hierarchy) and [the tutorial](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/datastructures.html#tuples-and-sequences):

> A special problem is the construction of tuples containing 0 or 1
>   items: the syntax has some extra quirks to accommodate these. Empty
>   tuples are constructed by an empty pair of parentheses; a tuple with
>   one item is constructed by following a value with a comma (it is not
>   sufficient to enclose a single value in parentheses).

Also, use `'reserve.views.view_reviews'` instead of merely `'view_reviews'`, thus:

```
reverse('reserve.views.view_reviews', args=(p.id,))
```

Check [the doc of reverse](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/urls/#django.core.urlresolvers.reverse)

Comment: I used to have that previously.  When I change it back to args=(p.id,) I get the error: Reverse for 'view_reviews' with arguments '(1,)' and keyword arguments '{}' not found.

Comment: @sharataka check the update, you could also use [the url pattern name](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/urls/#id2)

Answer (score 2):

Since your pattern assigns a match to a variable, it is considered a keyword argument, so you should adjust the call to reverse.

`return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('view_reviews', kwargs={'product_id':p.id})`

Comment: I made this change and I get the error "NoReverseMatch at /products/1/add_review/: Reverse for 'view_reviews' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments '{'product_id': 1}' not found.  This is strange because when I use the hardcoded version, there is a product_id with value 1.  Also, I'm not sure why the error is for "add_review"...shouldn't it be redirecting to view_reviews?

Comment: This doesn't matter actually.

Answer (score 0):

that's because the args need tuple, but when you use the args=(p.id), actually, the python will think is integer p.id, you can look the source code django 1.6 as follow:

```
def reverse(viewname, urlconf=None, args=None, kwargs=None, prefix=None, current_app=None):
if urlconf is None:
    urlconf = get_urlconf()
resolver = get_resolver(urlconf)
args = args or []
kwargs = kwargs or {}
if prefix is None:
    prefix = get_script_prefix()
if not isinstance(viewname, six.string_types):
    view = viewname
else:
    parts = viewname.split(':')
    parts.reverse()
    view = parts[0]
    path = parts[1:]
    resolved_path = []
    ns_pattern = ''
    while path:
        ns = path.pop()

        # Lookup the name to see if it could be an app identifier
        try:
            app_list = resolver.app_dict[ns]
            # Yes! Path part matches an app in the current Resolver
            if current_app and current_app in app_list:
                # If we are reversing for a particular app,
                # use that namespace
                ns = current_app
            elif ns not in app_list:
                # The name isn't shared by one of the instances
                # (i.e., the default) so just pick the first instance
                # as the default.
                ns = app_list[0]
        except KeyError:
            pass

        try:
            extra, resolver = resolver.namespace_dict[ns]
            resolved_path.append(ns)
            ns_pattern = ns_pattern + extra
        except KeyError as key:
            if resolved_path:
                raise NoReverseMatch(
                    "%s is not a registered namespace inside '%s'" %
                    (key, ':'.join(resolved_path)))
            else:
                raise NoReverseMatch("%s is not a registered namespace" %
                                     key)
    if ns_pattern:
        resolver = get_ns_resolver(ns_pattern, resolver)

return iri_to_uri(resolver._reverse_with_prefix(view, prefix, *args, **kwargs))
```

look this iri_to_uri(resolver._reverse_with_prefix(view, prefix, *args, **kwargs)), it use *args, so you should ensure args is a sequence,

according the docs, tuple with one item should add the comma to create, you code should be this:

```
return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('view_reviews', args=(p.id,)))
```